# 401k decisions when living overseas

Tags: united-states, 401k

I have $95000 in a 401k and am now 58 years old - the money was paid in when I lived in US but I left a few years ago and now live and work outside US - I am not a citizen of US - what is the best way for me to draw down the 401k and move it into a fund where I can get retirement income when I am say 66 years old with minimum tax implications - I still have US bank accounts

Answer (score 3):

1. See if there are any favorable tax treaties between your two countries.
   (check US state department - or find the nearest PWC, Deloitte, KPMG, these are global auditing firms that deal with international tax and compliance)
   A tax treaty could have possible goodies such as a lower more favorable tax or even a tax credit from. For instance, if you paid 28% tax in the US then your new country will give you a credit on the taxes owed to them. The point of tax treaties are to prevent double taxation, but in the effort to do so they often create their own new tax rates for transfers between countries.
2. You'll be better off just paying the 28% US income tax on your 401k distribution. And using the post-tax money as you please. US citizens are on the hook for income tax several years after they leave the US.

Comment: "several years after they leave the US". I don't believe there is a sunset clause. The rules stay the same regardless of how long you are out of the country - http://www.irs.gov/businesses/small/international/article/0,,id=97324,00.html.

Comment: @gef05 He was making a reference to expatriation and renouncing citizenship. Citizens have to pay taxes wherever they are no matter how long they are there, people that renounce their citizenship have to continue paying income taxes to the US IRS for several years